# Multiple Users Issue on Google Sheet which is being linked with Google Form

Tags: javascript

need help troubleshooting the issue. There is a breakdown of my Google sheet and the required behavior of it

1. Google sheet has a checkbox that triggers clicking and opening the Google form URL in a new tab with pre-filled info from that specific row.
2. Now the issue is, that if more than one user is working on this google sheet, 2nd user gets the drafted version of form that is being already in used by 1st User. Initially, it was like that.

I am unable to understand what is happening and how to correct it.